# Want WatiN to bypass FireFox Authentication Required dialog

Tags: c#, firefox, proxy, dialog, watin

The test is running on a windows network that requires proxy (squid) authentication to access external websites, say www.google.com for sake of example.

Some background things to note

- These sites cannot be added to the
  proxy white list.
- Same WatiN test passes in IE
- I have tried tweaking about:config
  ntlm settings to allow automatic
  passing of saved credentials
- www.google.com has been
  added to Local Intranet sites
- WatiN cannot use LogonDialogHandler
  to deal with this, like IE can

The title of the dialog is `Authentication Required` and reads `The proxy myproxy:8080 is requesting a user name and password.  The site says ""`, with a text field for `User Name`: and `Password`:

**Has anyone got any ideas of how to get around this?**

I'm hoping there is something FireFox specific that will allow me to automatically pass through the credentials.  An idea I might try is starting the browser with network credentials.

Comment: I hope that one day the same dialog support will be handle in FF than in IE....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one of the settings here will help:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Integrated_Authentication

EDIT:

This will be fixed in Firefox 4:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=521467

Comment: that is an interesting reference and could work for someone who logs with network credentials but I don't. My PC is on the network but I don't log into the network (for good reasons) and so credentials cannot be passed through.  I was hoping to pass through saved credentials (moz-proxy).

Comment: You'll need to set the `signon.autologin.proxy` preference to `true` in `about:config` (if it isn't set to true already).

Comment: very interesting update.  Just verified the auto proxy with FireFox 4 and it works a dream.  However, there is no stable jssh plugin for FF4 yet so would not be able to run WatiN tests against it yet.  That said, I think you've answered this question and I'll raise a separate one for jssh.  Thanks, that was a great find.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some references that might offer other solutions to get around the logon dialog.

In this post they solved it using WindowsAutomation:

[WatiN LogonDialogHandlers not working correctly in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841120/watin-logondialoghandlers-not-working-correctly-in-windows-7)

This solution passes the credentials in the url:

[how to impersonate a windows domain user for automated web testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975958/how-to-impersonate-a-windows-domain-user-for-automated-web-testing)

And this solution uses impersonation:

[Watin Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122385/watin-windows-authentication)

You could also use FiddlerCore to manipulate the response to the server:

[How to simulate http request using WatiN with specific HTTP referrer and query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362340/how-to-simulate-http-request-using-watin-with-specific-http-referrer-and-query-st)

HTH,
Jeroen