# Could not get Alert dialog with Firefox when using final WatiN version

Tags: firefox, dialog, watin

The code below works well with IE7, but when I switch to run with Firefox (from 3.0 to 3.6) I could not get the the Dialog. It raise error on line: DiaglogHandler.WaitUntilExists(10) "Dialog not available within 10 seconds." even though the dialog is there. I'm using the final WatiN release.

```
        string url = "https://www.xxx.com"
        Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = true;
        Settings.AutoCloseDialogs = false;
        //var browser = new IE();
        var browser = new FireFox();
        browser.GoTo(url);
        Image theButton = browser.Image(Find.By("id", "button"));
        AlertDialogHandler DiaglogHandler = new AlertDialogHandler();

        DialogWatcher theDialogWatcher = new DialogWatcher(new WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.Window(browser.hWnd));
        theDialogWatcher.Add(DiaglogHandler);
        theDialogWatcher.CloseUnhandledDialogs = false;

        theButton.ClickNoWait();

        DiaglogHandler.WaitUntilExists(10);
        Console.WriteLine(DiaglogHandler.Message);

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik WatiN does not deal well with Dialogs yet, though it is on the horizon.

It is possible to get around them, say passing an Enter to the browser or other javascript interaction.

I've had similar issues with [Authentication Required Dialogs in FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761782/want-watin-to-bypass-firefox-authentication-required-dialog)